# How to fetch OAuth2.0 Access Token and use this token to call RESTFul Web services using Java client code?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, oauth-2.0, java-client

I am new to write a Java client code to call RestFul web services. These web services using OAuth2.0 security. I have client-id and secret keys with me, but unable to call through Java program. How should I get access token out of this and use this token further for Web service API calls. Here is how I tried:

```
private static void authorizationProcess() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.ustream.tv/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=671c71f800c17f1d57f10eebeba2f42d230143cddji8&redirect_uri=www.ustream.tv");
    try {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet, context);
        System.out.println("Response status: " + httpResponse.getStatusLine());
        HttpRequest req = (HttpRequest) context.getAttribute(
                ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
        System.out.println("Last request URI: " + req.getRequestLine());
        RedirectLocations redirectLocations = (RedirectLocations) context.getAttribute(
                DefaultRedirectStrategy.REDIRECT_LOCATIONS);
        if (redirectLocations != null) {
            System.out.println("All intermediate redirects: " + redirectLocations.getAll());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(httpResponse.getEntity());
    } finally {
        httpGet.releaseConnection();
    }
}
}
```

Its giving Bad Request error message:

```
Response status: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Last request URI: GET /oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=671c71f800c17f1d57f10eebeba2f42d230143cddji8&    redirect_uri=www.ustream.tv HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute an Authorization Code grant in Java code but that grant type was designed for real browser interaction. You should rather look in to a grant type such as Resource Owner Password Credentials or Client Credentials which both can be used with non-browser-based Clients.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I tried grant type as Client Credentials and its working fine now from Standalone java application.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment to the Hans Z. answer, but I think it's actually an authorization request for **Implicit grant** (`response_type=token` is used, details [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1)). It could be Android client for example. Some APIs requires `http` or `https` in the `redirect_uri`, which is missing in your example. You may give it a shot (keep in mind the [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) too)..

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now I am able to write and execute the client code from a standalone java application.